# How to create table during Django tests with managed = False?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-1.7, django-migrations

From the [oficial documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/options/#managed):

> For tests involving models with `managed=False`, it’s up to you to ensure the correct tables are created as part of the test setup.

I don't know how to create the tables as part of the test setup. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7020966/842697) and the accepted answer doesn't work for me. I think this is because the migrations files. The configuration is in the migrations files, to change the values "on the fly" don't have any effect.

What's the way to solve this in Django 1.7+?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Modify the fixtures and add the SQL to generate the tables:

```
#0001_initial.py (or followings)
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL("CREATE TABLE..."),
        ...
    ]
```

I'm a "migrations newbie" so I don't know if this is the best option. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be similar in Django 1.7+. When you are going to run the tests you should manage those models with Django (just for testing purposes). 
This conversion should be done before creating tables and Django allows you to give a class instance setting up TEST_RUNNER in your settings.py

```
# settings_test.py
TEST_RUNNER = 'utils.test_runner.ManagedModelTestRunner'

# test_runner.py
from django.test.runner import DiscoverRunner

class ManagedModelTestRunner(DiscoverRunner):
    """
    Test runner that automatically makes all unmanaged models in your Django
    project managed for the duration of the test run, so that one doesn't need
    to execute the SQL manually to create them.
    """  
    def setup_test_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
        from django.db.models.loading import get_models
        super(ManagedModelTestRunner, self).setup_test_environment(*args,
                                                                   **kwargs)
        self.unmanaged_models = [m for m in get_models(only_installed=False)
                                 if not m._meta.managed]
        for m in self.unmanaged_models:
            m._meta.managed = True

    def teardown_test_environment(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ManagedModelTestRunner, self).teardown_test_environment(*args, **kwargs)
        # reset unmanaged models
        for m in self.unmanaged_models:
            m._meta.managed = False
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. I think the problem is that Django now use migrations and this code doesn't change them.