# How to test unmanaged models using pytest-django

Tags: django, django-models, pytest, pytest-django

In my django project, I have 5 applications, with total 15 models,and all of them are unmanaged. I've written some tests in pytest-django, and when I run them, they fail due to not being able to find tables.

How can I create database entries for all these models so that the tests don't fail?

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to get this to work on `Django==4.0.4`, `pytest-django==4.5.2` and none of the results I could find out there worked for me. This is what I could figure out:

```
# add this to conftest.py
@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtestloop():
    from django.apps import apps
    unmanaged_models = []
    for app in apps.get_app_configs():
        unmanaged_models += [m for m in app.get_models()
                             if not m._meta.managed]
    for m in unmanaged_models:
        m._meta.managed = True
```

For this to work you need to add a `--no-migrations` hook to your pytest settings.

It seems intuitive to think that we can achieve what we need by overriding `django_db_setup`, and that is the solution provided in other answers on SO. However I was not able to get this to work, that might have something to do with changes to the order of execution of these fixtures over the years, I am not sure.

Excerpt from the current `pytest-django` docs:

> pytest-django calls django.setup() automatically. If you want to do anything before this, you have to create a pytest plugin and use the pytest_load_initial_conftests() hook

[Read more](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#changing-your-app-before-django-gets-set-up)

EDIT:

- Added a note regarding the need to run this without migrations as suggested by @AngryUbuntuNerd

Comment: You haven't provided a link to "read more"

Comment: My bad, I added the link to docs, thanks for the heads up

Comment: note that you need to run pytest with `--no-migrations` for this to work

Answer (score -1):

You can override the `django_db_setup` fixture in `conftest.py` file:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def django_db_setup(django_db_blocker):

    with django_db_blocker.unblock():

        from django.apps import apps

        models_list = apps.get_models()
        for model in models_list:
            with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
                schema_editor.create_model(model)

                if model._meta.db_table not in connection.introspection.table_names():
                    raise ValueError(
                        "Table `{table_name}` is missing in test database.".format(
                            table_name=model._meta.db_table
                        )
                    )

        yield

        for model in models_list:
            with connection.schema_editor() as schema_editor:
                schema_editor.delete_model(model)
```

This will create the tables for unmanaged models before running tests, and delete those tables after test.

Comment: That didn't work for me, but I've found a good solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60349699/9457813