# Pytest causes 'invalid object name' error while setting up test databases

Tags: python, sql-server, django, docker, pytest

**UPDATE:** Solved by https://stackoverflow.com/a/72399235/20422987

I'm trying to use Pytest to run unit tests on a Django application, but I'm having trouble interacting with Django's database models. A majority of the models in my application have the `managed=False` value set, since they're connected to external DBs. I'm using a script that sets the them to `managed=True` when running the test, because I was having issues with the test DBs being created without any contents.

The problem is that whenever I run a test that needs DB access and the system starts creating test databases, it throws an error as soon as it hits one of the tables whose model has been changed to `managed=True`. Looking at the verbose traceback from Pytest, it seems like the system is trying to query the test database for the entire content of the table in question, and failing because the table doesn't exist.

This only happens when one or more models for external have been changed to `managed=True`, either manually or using the script mentioned earlier. If I don't change any of the models, the test DB creation process works without errors, but the resulting test DBs don't contain any tables. The one model in the application which does not use an external DB, and thus is already set to `managed=True`, does not seem to cause any errors while creating test DBs.

An example error traceback can be found below. `Students_with_Holds` is a table that exists in the `Coursematch` external DB, and the Django model for it has been modified to have `managed=True` for the test. The test itself is doing absolutely nothing (it's just `assert True`) but the `@pytest.mark.django_db(databases=['Coursematch'])` decorator has been applied to it.

```
------- ERROR at setup of TestLetterGenerator.test_db_access --------

self = <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7f72edc60730>
sql = 'SELECT [Students_with_Holds].[Person_ID_Number], [Students_with_Holds].[Hold_Type_Code], [Students_with_Holds].[Hold_...h_Holds].[Date_Applied] FROM [Students_with_Holds] ORDER BY [Students_with_Holds].[Person_ID_Number] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS'
params = ()
ignored_wrapper_args = (False, {'connection': <mssql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f72ee2c1e80>, 'cursor': <django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper object at 0x7f72edc60730>})

    def _execute(self, sql, params, *ignored_wrapper_args):
        self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
            if params is None:
                # params default might be backend specific.
                return self.cursor.execute(sql)
            else:
>               return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:84: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <mssql.base.CursorWrapper object at 0x7f72edc60b50>
sql = 'SELECT [Students_with_Holds].[Person_ID_Number], [Students_with_Holds].[Hold_Type_Code], [Students_with_Holds].[Hold_...h_Holds].[Date_Applied] FROM [Students_with_Holds] ORDER BY [Students_with_Holds].[Person_ID_Number] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS'
params = ()

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.last_sql = sql
        sql = self.format_sql(sql, params)
        params = self.format_params(params)
        self.last_params = params
        try:
>           return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E           pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Students_with_Holds'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssql/base.py:621: ProgrammingError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

request = <SubRequest '_django_db_marker' for <Function test_db_access>>

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def _django_db_marker(request) -> None:
        """Implement the django_db marker, internal to pytest-django."""
        marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("django_db")
        if marker:
>           request.getfixturevalue("_django_db_helper")

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py:465: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_django/fixtures.py:122: in django_db_setup
    db_cfg = setup_databases(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/test/utils.py:179: in setup_databases
    connection.creation.create_test_db(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:90: in create_test_db
    self.connection._test_serialized_contents = self.serialize_db_to_string()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:136: in serialize_db_to_string
    serializers.serialize("json", get_objects(), indent=None, stream=out)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/serializers/__init__.py:129: in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py:90: in serialize
    for count, obj in enumerate(queryset, start=1):
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py:133: in get_objects
    yield from queryset.iterator()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:353: in _iterator
    yield from self._iterable_class(self, chunked_fetch=use_chunked_fetch, chunk_size=chunk_size)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:51: in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:1175: in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:66: in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:75: in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:84: in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py:90: in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py:84: in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <mssql.base.CursorWrapper object at 0x7f72edc60b50>
sql = 'SELECT [Students_with_Holds].[Person_ID_Number], [Students_with_Holds].[Hold_Type_Code], [Students_with_Holds].[Hold_...h_Holds].[Date_Applied] FROM [Students_with_Holds] ORDER BY [Students_with_Holds].[Person_ID_Number] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS'
params = ()

    def execute(self, sql, params=None):
        self.last_sql = sql
        sql = self.format_sql(sql, params)
        params = self.format_params(params)
        self.last_params = params
        try:
>           return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
E           django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'Students_with_Holds'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mssql/base.py:621: ProgrammingError
```

Comment: can you share some of your code + the traceback you're getting?

Comment: added a traceback and a description of the test, which is literally just "assert True" with the db access decorator applied