# create an other table during tests manually in django webapp

Tags: mysql, django, automated-tests

I'm creating some tests in my django web app with selenium.
Django create a test database with all tables.

In my case however I have a model Users.
I want that django create also users table when I run this command in terminal
`python3.9 manage.py test -v3`

This command goes in error:

```
Running post-migrate handlers for application contenttypes
Adding content type 'contenttypes | contenttype'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Running post-migrate handlers for application sessions
Adding content type 'sessions | session'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Running post-migrate handlers for application pygiustizia
Adding content type 'pygiustizia | member'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
Adding permission 'Permission object (None)'
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
test_login (pygiustizia.tests.test_views_topics.ViewsTopicsTestCase) ... nel costruttore model Users
ERROR

======================================================================
ERROR: test_login (pygiustizia.tests.test_views_topics.ViewsTopicsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 89, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 75, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/nicola/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_civiledb.users' doesn't exist")
```

**EDIT**
I access to the table users that I want create manually for test by this model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection
import pymysql

class Users(models.Model):

    firstname=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname=models.CharField(max_length=100) 
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    admin=models.IntegerField()
    createdAt=models.DateTimeField(db_column="created_at")

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("nel costruttore model Users")

    def getAdmin(self):
        return self.admin

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'users'

    def getUser(self,username):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''SELECT id, 
                            username, 
                            password,
                            admin,
                            firstname,
                            lastname,
                            created_at 
                            FROM users 
                            WHERE username = %s''',[username])

        result = cursor.fetchone()
                 
        return result

    def setPassword(self,userId,password):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        
        try:
            cursor.execute('''UPDATE users  
                            SET password = %s 
                            WHERE id = %s''',[password,userId])
            connection.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            connection.rollback()
            return False
        finally:
            connection.close()
        
        return True
```

A solution is to create "sql create" schema run it in testcase in setUp and drop it on tearDown.

Comment: Have you [created your migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#makemigrations) before trying to run your test suite?

Comment: Yes, I have, but I have one table called "users" that I have created manually. I didn't use django middleware authentication. If you want I can post my model Users.

Comment: Please do post your model. And could you expand on why you created that table manually? Django shouldn't manage this table, if I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, Django shouldn't manage user test_civiledb.users. I want test manually. Ok one moment that I edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the concept you are looking for here are [unmanaged models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/options/#managed). By setting the appropriate Meta option you can tell Django that it shouldn't handle the table lifecycle for you.

To answer your question, [using `SchemaEditor` on test setup and teardown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49800437/2487231) seems like a particularly clean way to achieve what you are looking for.